# Checklist and radio button alternative

Tags: forms

## What is the best way to display this information?

### Overview

I am in the process of creating an application form for a Scottish college. We have 8-9 accessibility statements for applicants to select in one question.

#### My challenge

Within these 9 statements we have 3 that are not part of a checkbox selection and are more related to radio buttons - because they shouldn't be selected with any other statement. With all the options on the page there is a bigger risk of cognitive overload that I'm very aware of too.

**Statements example (checkboxes)**

- A specific learning difficulty such as dyslexia, dyspraxia or ADHDA social/communication impairment such as Asperger’s syndrome/other autistic spectrum disorder
- A long standing illness or health condition such as cancer, HIV, diabetes, chronic heart disease or epilepsy
- Deaf or hearing impairment

**3 other statements (radio buttons)**

- A disability impairment or medical condition that is not listed above
- No known disability
- Prefer not to answer

#### What would be the best way to display the 9 statements?

To improve skim reading I've broken the statement up and added a bold title with further information under the title (hoping this will get past approval). But what is the best way to include the 3 other statements?

**Guidelines of list**

- Applicants can select multiple statements which are true
- The wording can not change e.g be shortened
- The UI component needs to be clear and easy to read/select on desktop & mobile
- Improving accessibility is our main reason for updating the form

Wireframe example:

[image: wireframe list of checkboxes]

Comment: To consider as well: https://www.siteimprove.com/glossary/accessible-fonts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements of the three radio buttons belong to another group of checkboxes, usually called `Other`. Indenting the radio button group below the `Other` checkbox will suffice, so you can add an expand/collapse or enable/disable effect when is checked or unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The title is a "yes or no" question
and the checkboxes above are part of the yes
if user selects yes, you can then ask them to select which disability they have + the first statement `A disability impairment or medical condition that is not listed above` as "other" as it's title
no = No known disability
and another option - I prefer not to answer

to conclude:
question: "Do you have a disability or learning difficulty?"

3 radio buttons:

- yes
- no (No known disability)
- I prefer no to answer

if yes is selected,

question: "select all statements that best describe your support needs."

show all checkboxes + add "other- A disability impairment or medical condition that is not listed above" as the last one.